# Creating a modal success notification for Stripe checkout

Tags: php, jquery, stripe-payments

I'm trying to make the success of a stripe checkout a little nicer then a `div` that says "Thank you for your submission". I'm looking to add a modal that will have this thank you message. But I'm new to PHP and I keep breaking the stripe token. I am not sure what way to go about this. I've seen custom submit buttons with AJAX but not sure if that is needed. Thanks in advance!

**Here is my HTML:**

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['cart_errors'])) : ?>
    <div class="thank-you"><?=$_POST['cart_errors']?></div>
<?php endif // errors ?>
```

**Here is the JS**

```
var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#cart-payment-form');
  console.log(response);
  if (response.error) {
    // Show the errors on the form
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    // token contains id, last4, and card type
    var token = response.id;
    // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
    // and submit
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};

$('#cart-payment-form').submit(function(event) {
  var $form = $(this);

  // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
  $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

  Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

  // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
  return false;
});

$('#thank-you').dialog({
  height: 140,
  modal: true
});
```

**Here is my PHP:**

```
$cart_stripe_secret_key = get_option("cart_stripe_secret_key");
Stripe::setApiKey($cart_stripe_secret_key);

$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

try
{
    $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $totalCharge*100, // amount in cents, again
    "currency" => "usd",
    "card" => $token,
    "description" => $_POST['surgecart_email']
));
}
catch(Stripe_CardError $e)
{
    $_POST['cart_errors'] = "Whoops! There was a problem with your card. Try again?";
return FALSE;
}

$_POST['cart_errors'] = "Thank you for your order!";
```

Comment: If you want to submit your form without reloading your whole page, you'll need to use AJAX.

Comment: You can also do the PRG pattern, the result will be shown in the modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly suggest using Stripe Checkout which uses modal and ajax address lookup. For the successful return you can use a bootstrap modal http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/.

In whatever page you redirect to after the successful transaction, house the modal code, but keep the auto pop in a php If echoing out the 'activate modal' js under the correct circumstances. Something like this:

```
<?php
 if($stripe_response()){

  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
          $(window).load(function(){
          $('#myModal').modal({
              show: true});
                });
         </script>"; 

}
?>
```

further, you can add successful or declined messaging in the if().